# Static content serve from subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have **domain.localhost** and **assets.domain.localhost**. Virtual host in htppd.conf is set correctly.

I have folder in root **"public/"** and there are other folders like **images, scripts, styles**. I need serve content from domain.localhost and static images, scripts and styles server from assets.domain.localhost.

**I have this code in htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !assets\.domain\.localhost
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|ico|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://assets.domain.localhost/$1 [L]
```

**First question:** Is it correct way to load assets separatly and decrease count of request from domain?

**Second question:** I checked it in firebug

[image: image of network is here]

and everything was loaded from assets.domain.localhost, but css and js was loaded twice. First time from domain.localhost with 302 code (just some byte but is it request) and than from assets.domain.localhost with 304 code. What I doing wrong?

**Update**

This workaround increase result in PageSpeed Insights, but decrease in Webpage performance test. In second one is longer response from server and assets are not cache anymore. I have this one in htaccess for that:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate"
<IfModule deflate_module>
  <IfModule filter_module>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Before changes, it worked, not caching does't work.

**Update2**

Ok problem is with first request to **domain.localhost**, that is not cached, secon request to **assets.domain.localhost** is cached. How to rid first unecessary request?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you change your HTML to contain the Asset-URLs with your assets.domain.localhost Domain.

If you leave your HTML as is, the Browser will request the files from domain.localhost, receive a "302 Found" from Apache (as defined in your .htaccess) and then request the files from assets.domain.localhost again.

If it is not possible to change the Asset-Links in your HTML you can try something like [mod_substitute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html) to replace the links on-thy-fly. But i've never tried this in a real-world-scenario.

Comment: I din't change my html. I don't want adress images, etc. absolutely. My idea is let relative path to images, js, css but in htaccess set loading from assets.domain.localhost. It is possible? Is logical what you write in second paragraph, but why this behavior is only within js and css, and images are loaded directly from asets subdomain?

Comment: It should be like CDN. Repair the same behavior like css and js have jpegs, png have not